# Azure Logic App to Copy File From BLOB to FTPS

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, ftps

I am trying to copy a file from an Azure BLOB container into a 3rd party FTPS site using an Azure Logic App. The first step of connecting to the BLOB container when a new file is added works fine. I cannot seem to find the right combination of settings for the second and final step, which attempts to push the file to the FTPS site. The second step runs and after 4 retries fails. In the Logic App step designer, I see that I can add an FTP action or an SFTP action, but not FTPS. I would rather not code this in C#.

Does anyone know if this can be accomplished using an Azure Logic App?

I appreciate it...

Comment: Post it as comment in learn.microsoft.com

Comment: Also, the FTP connector is not compatible with ***implicit*** FTPS (FTP over SSL). The FTP connector only supports ***explicit*** FTPS (FTP over SSL).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp